# How can I run a rails server virtually?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to be able to work on my app but I won't have internet. So how can I run the app? Would regular rails s do the trick or is a network required for that?

Comment: Have a look here (`rails server`): http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#starting-up-the-web-server

Comment: How will you be able to work on the app without google and stackoverflow? You need internet at least for that :)

Answer (score 2):

`rails s` runs the server locally.  Furthermore, I think you misunderstand the term `virtual`.

`rails s` will get the job done.  Just run that command, then go to `http://localhost:4000`  (or whatever port it runs on)

Comment: Well I assumed that it required a network because `rails s` runs on a local network (which is why I used the term virtual), if it doesn't that's great, thanks!

Comment: ah, yea. no it doesn't run on a local network, it simply opens a port on your local computer. that's it :)

Comment: Are you sure? Because when I run it at work I can access it from other computers on the network, is that because there's a plugin hat does that?